# JPanel layout Issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have a slight issue with adding two JPanels to a main main panel.  I've put it as a quick example of what I want to do since you don't want to be looking through loads of lines of unnecessary code :).  I want panel one to be added first (**north**) and then panel two (**south**).  I've tried using Border layout and positioning them invoking north and south on **BorderLayout** when adding the panels but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

```
private JPanel one,two;

public Example(){
    one = new JPanel();
    one.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    two = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,8));
    two.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    one.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    two.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
    mainpanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
    mainpanel.add(one);
    mainpanel.add(two);
    add(mainpanel);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: "you don't want to be looking through loads of lines of unnecessary code"  No I don't, but an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) might help.  BTW - what behavior did you expect?  What about the current behavior does not match that expectation?  Did you have a *question*, or were you just sharing that code snippet with us?

Comment: BTW - since when does 2 x 400x400 panels fit into a 500x500 container?  It is fortunate in this case that layouts mostly ignore `setSize()`, and will overrule the preferred size for other values as needed.  It is rarely necessary to set the size or preferred size of components in Java GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use BorderLayout, then BorderLayout.CENTER takes up as much space as it can, and the other directions take only what they need.  If you add extra stuff to the JPanels, they will get bigger, based on the needs of the objects they contain.

If you want to just divide the space evenly within the main JPanel, try this:

```
JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
```

That creates a GridLayout with 2 rows and 1 column...

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it wasn't working but I found that I declared the frame layout somewhere which was messing things up.  Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. There was issue that apparently if you install grid layout on a panel and you add no components it will not take space.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel one, two;

    public Example()
    {
        one = new JPanel();
        two = new JPanel();///new GridLayout(7, 8));
        one.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        two.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainpanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        mainpanel.add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainpanel.add(two, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setContentPane(mainpanel);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Example f = new Example();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Good [sscce](http://sscce.org), but the empty `GridLayout` is not a problem. Set a preferred size on `one` and `two`, give `mainpanel` a `GridLayout`, and use `pack()` (instead of `setSize()`) to see the effect.

Comment: no needed call 'setContentPane();' because that's job for declared 'LayoutManager', and pack minim. 'setVisible()' into 'InvokeLater' (EDT), correctly would be whole 'main' method

Comment: @trashgod setting the prefSize on the (still) empty panel is cheating :-)

Comment: @kleopatra is right; setting a preferred size is contrived, but it's a way to illuminate the order prescribed by [`getPreferredSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) in `JComponent`.

Comment: @trashgod What I meant by saying GridLayout 'is a problem' was to highlight that for some layout managers if you do not have components in them they simply will not take space which is not true in case of FlowLayout (which is the default one for a JPanel), thus you can see some space is taken by panel `two` without setting the preferred size. Which I agree there is no point to call, unless you know how a layout manager interprets it and what you are after.

Comment: @mKorbel you are right, the code runs now on EDT. I have forgotten about it again. I am not calling pack since I want the middle part of the main panel to be visible too. As it goes to setting the content I prefer to use that as it ignore declarative & informative then just adding element to the default content pane, which then we do not need.

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` ignores the values set in setSize method of contained components. If you want to control the size of each component, consider using [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).